# How come I only get 1 tower bux?

Tags: android, tiny-tower

The Tiny Tower wiki VERY strongly suggests, in multiple places, that employing a bitizen in their dream job will net 2 tower bux. However I've only ever gotten one bux as far as I can tell. Is the wiki out of date? Am I only getting 1 bux because I'm playing the android version?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you playing on iOS or Android?

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Comment: I was really hoping that would help me answer this. =( I play on iOS and have been getting 2 bux per dream job assignment.

Comment: On the early version of the game you only got 1 towerbux per dream job, this was later updated, it's possible this update was only for the iOS version

Comment: Android here -  I too only get one tower bux. Is there a way to see the app model number?

Comment: In iOS you can see version at the top of the menu, right in the middle above the settings button

Comment: Note that this has now changed to correctly display 2 bux in the Android version.

Comment: Considering this is now fixed, should I delete this question?

Comment: @aslum no, we could close it as too localized though. People that have old versions might still be having the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watch your bux when you place them in their dream job. I play on the Thunderbolt which is an Android device and although the message says you've earned **a** towerbux! You acctually get **two**, I litterally just tested to verify.

This is most likely becasue the developers are swamped with work trying to get the Android version running smoooth and they missed that dialog box text change.

**Note:** If you *are* only getting one Bux then you should send a message to the developers with your device name, becasue they don't even know you're getting shafted.

**4/26/12:** The message is now displaying properly as of the latest patch.